# Complexity class of a function

Tags: python, code-complexity

I apologize if my question isn't appropriate for this website, but this is the only place I know that can answer computer science questions.

For my quiz, we were told to calculate and simplify the complexity class of a function. I understand most of the concepts and everything, but I cannot understand why `O(1)`is incorrect for the line `aset = set(alist)`. The correct answer is supposed to be `O(N)`, but I don't see why this is.

Here is the complete function:

```
def sum_to_b(alist,asum):
    aset = set(alist)
    for v in alist:
        if asum-v in aset:
            return (v,asum-v)
    return None
```

Comment: Some important information is missing from this question. Can you post the function's source code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over each element of 'alist' exactly one time (assuming it is regular iterable) to build 'aset' set.

Comment: Is it done as a built-in thing for python? It can iterate over each element without my saying so?

Comment: @Tyler: Built-in functions like `set` can do anything you could do with a function you wrote, and you could write a `set` function that iterates over its argument.